# How to resolve error "Exceeded maximum execution time" in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function "myTrigger" on a Google Sheet scheduled to run once every 8 hours with a trigger.

The function contains 6 other functions, as shown below:

```
function myTrigger() 
{
  fetchData();
  fetchData2();
  fetchData3();
  fetchData4();
  myEnd();
  delTest();
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that the total execution time of myTrigger is more than 6 mins, and it throws up an error sometimes. Are there any workarounds such that I'm able to run all those functions one after the other and still stay within the time limit?

Comment: In your showing script, if you are thinking that your 6 functions have no modification points for reducing the process cost, how about sepalating the executing functions? But, if this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Have you tried to determine which of your other functions is running the slowest.  Try writing times to the execution log.

Comment: [so] already have a lot of questions about this error. Please spend something learning about the differents approaches to solve it. If need further help, please show what you tried to solve the problem and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

#### Run consecutive functions

Edit your function names in to the function names array `a`.  Run the launchstartdialog. Push the start button.  I'm not sure how long the callback will wait but it works for about 30 seconds so far.

gs:

```
function launchstartdialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah4'));
}

function executeFunctionByName(func) {
  this[func]();
}
```

html('ah4.html'):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <input type="Button" value="Start" onClick="start();" />
  <script>
  var n;
  var a = ["func1","func2","func3"];//Enter your function names
  window.onload = function(){
      n = 0;
    }
    function start() {
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(obj => {
        if(n < a.length) {
          start()
        }
        ;
      })
      .executeFunctionByName(a[n++])
    }
  console.log('ah4');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```